# EAR is packing two copies of WAR and JAR projects

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

My Maven EAR project packs my EAR with two copies of each of my libraries. One copy is always appended with the version (In my case 1.0-SNAPSHOT). Is there something screwed up in my POMs?

I keep getting these type of errors when i try and deploy to server:

Servlet [blah...] and Servlet [blah..] have the same url pattern: [/RegistrationService_V10].

[image]

My EAR project POM looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>AlmexOffice</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.huwag</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.huwag</groupId>
    <artifactId>AlmexOffice-ear</artifactId>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>AlmexOFfice-ear JavaEE6 Assembly</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <version>6</version>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>AlmexOffice-ear</finalName>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.huwag</groupId>
            <artifactId>AlmexOffice-ejb</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.huwag</groupId>
            <artifactId>AlmexOffice-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Is it also happening with Maven CLI, not only inside NetBeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the maven-ear-plugin, you have to specify your ejbmodule and webmodule

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <configuration>
      <modules>
        <ejbModule>
           <groupId>com.huwag</groupId>
           <artifactId>AlmexOffice-ejb</artifactId>
        </ejbModule>
        <webModule>
           <groupId>com.huwag</groupId>
           <artifactId>AlmexOffice-web</artifactId>
           <contextRoot>/custom-context-root</contextRoot>
         </webModule>
      </modules>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Could you give us the feedback if it works better?

Comment: are you sure? The tutorial says that for my EAR project I just have to define them in my [dependency] tags. I will try that out.

Comment: seems to have improved a lot :) Let me play around with it before I green tick you. I'm not 100% certain yet that this has fixed it.

Comment: no problems anymore. But it seems a bit redundant that i have to declare in [dependency] as well as [ejbModule]. Oh well i dont care :) it works now anyway

Comment: I think the difference is that in the dependency you specified the version and not the in the modules tag